# Espocrm with Traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, espocrm

I want to use traefik for Espocrm docker-compose.yml file and i tried something but it didn't work can someone help me out this situation.
I'm using traefik because easy to configure and with ssl but i think something went wrong with Espocrm docker-compose.yml file.

> I will add my docker-compose.yml file down below.

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: espocrm
      MYSQL_USER: espocrm
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: database_password
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password  
    networks:
      - espocrm
    volumes:
      - /storage/espocrm/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    labels:
        - "traefik.enable=false"

  espocrm:
    image: espocrm/espocrm
    container_name: espocrm
    environment:
      ESPOCRM_DATABASE_HOST: mysql
      ESPOCRM_DATABASE_USER: espocrm
      ESPOCRM_DATABASE_PASSWORD: database_password
      ESPOCRM_ADMIN_USERNAME: admin
      ESPOCRM_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
      ESPOCRM_SITE_URL: "https://espocrm.mydomain.com"
    networks:
      - espocrm
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /storage/espocrm:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.espocrm.rule=Host(`espocrm.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.espocrm.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.espocrm.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.espocrm.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.espocrm.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
      - "traefik.http.routers.espocrm.tls.domains[0].main=espocrm.mydomain.com"
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 8080

  espocrm-daemon:
    image: espocrm/espocrm
    container_name: espocrm-daemon
    networks:
      - espocrm
    volumes:
      - /storage/espocrm:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    entrypoint: docker-daemon.sh

  espocrm-websocket:
    image: espocrm/espocrm
    container_name: espocrm-websocket    
    environment:
      ESPOCRM_CONFIG_USE_WEB_SOCKET: "true"
      ESPOCRM_CONFIG_WEB_SOCKET_URL: "ws://espocrm.mydomain.com"
      ESPOCRM_CONFIG_WEB_SOCKET_ZERO_M_Q_SUBSCRIBER_DSN: "tcp://*:7777"
      ESPOCRM_CONFIG_WEB_SOCKET_ZERO_M_Q_SUBMISSION_DSN: "tcp://espocrm-websocket:7777"
    volumes:
      - /storage/espocrm:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - espocrm
    restart: always
    entrypoint: docker-websocket.sh
    expose:
      - 8081
      - 7777

networks:
  espocrm:
    driver: bridge
  proxy:
    external:
      name: "traefik_proxy"

volumes:
  mysql:
  espocrm:
```

Comment: Your post is incomplete. What specific error are you getting? Post the full log output